# Redefining plugin directory path when accessing a plugin directly?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to create a plugin for Wordpress in such a way that it can also be incorporated into a theme and accessed directly. I've figured out with some digging how to include the plugin if the class hasn't been loaded but I'm having trouble redefining the plugin path for any CSS or js that the plugin requires. Is there a way to redefine the plugin URL and directory path in functions so that it points to the correct directory and overrides the plugin's default?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, change the exit part to whatever is desired. redirect or something

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. Trying to use villa shortcakes plugin as an example. Ideally I'd like to be able to incorporate into a theme OR use it as a plugin. So far I have this which loads the plugin but the path of the css and js are broken: 
`add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_load_plugin');
function my_load_plugin() {
 if (!class_exists('ZillaShortcodes')) { 
  include_once( TEMPLATEPATH. '/zilla-shortcodes/zilla-shortcodes.php' );   
  }
}`

Comment: see if you can paste your sample code so I can have a better look?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by creating a filter:

```
define( 'THEME_MODE', apply_filters( 'theme_mode', false ) );
```

Then creating a if/else function:

```
if ( false == THEME_MODE) {
        define( 'PLUGIN_URI', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
        define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
  } else {
    if ( true == THEME_MODE ) {
          $path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_stylesheet(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
          define( 'PLUGIN_URI',  trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_bloginfo('template_directory') ). $path));
          define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_bloginfo('template_directory') ) . $path ));
    }
  }
```

Then I called the function in functions.php

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_shortcodes');
add_filter( 'theme_mode', '__return_true' );
function load_shortcodes() {
if( ! class_exists('Shortcodes') ) {    
    // load if not already loaded
    include_once( TEMPLATEPATH. '/shortcodes/aa-shortcodes.php' );      
    }
}
```